# Projecting and blending multiple images onto an object with UV Project modifiers

Tags: scripting, uv, camera

My question is similar to "projecting multiple images onto an object" and it seems to me the answer "Projecting multiple images onto an object with UV project modifiers" is close to the solution. An improvement in this part of the script (if possible) would be required :

```
    #Assign polygon to its corresponding camera considering faces most aligned to camera view
for p in obj.data.polygons:
    normalInWorld = Vector( p.normal )
    normalInWorld.rotate( rotation_world )
    camSetting, maxDot = max( ((c, normalInWorld.dot( c.zInWorld)) for c in camSettingList), key=itemgetter(1) )
    camSetting.polygons.add( p.index )
```

Instead of selecting the best oriented face face, the improvement would, for example, create an new UV-map that would blend images from different cameras projection with an influence according to face orientation relative to camera.

For example, if two orthographic cameras have a 45° angle relative to the face, the UV map would be assigned a blend with 50% of first camera projection and 50% of second camera projection.

A thresold on the scalar product normalInWorld . c.zInWorld would be needed to discard too badly oriented face.

Does it seem feasible ?